# Google Cloud Speech Api Discovering Supported Languages via Http Request

Tags: google-cloud-speech

Is it possible to get [list of supported languages](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/languages) via a http request just as in [translate api](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/discovering-supported-languages)? Or do we all have to hardcode the list of languages in our code from the [supported languages page](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/languages)?

Answer (score 0):

The API specification for the Speech API does not offer such a feature. You may verify the API capabilities, and read method descriptions on the "APIs & Reference" documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/apis).